# $B(t+a)-B(a)$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

> Let $B(t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion and fix $a>0$.
>
> I would like to prove that $W(t)=B(t+a)-B(a)$ is also a Brownian motion.

So:

$1)$ $W(0)=B(a)-B(a)=0$ a.e.

2) \begin{align*} \DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov} \Cov(W(s),W(t)) &=\Cov(B(s+a)-B(a),B(t+a)-B(a)) \\&=\Cov(B(s+a),B(t+a)) \\&=\min(s+a,t+a) \\ &=\min(s,t). \end{align*}

$3)$ $t\mapsto W(t)$ is continuous as a composed of continuous functions.

$4)$ I need to check that $W$ is gaussian with mean zero.

To prove that $W$ is gaussian it's equivalent to $(W(t_1),\ldots,W(t_n))$ to be a gaussian vector. I cannot figure out how can I prove that.

I tried with the characteristic function $$\phi_W(u)=\exp({u^tB(a))}\phi_{B(t+a)}(u).$$

Any help ?

Comment: Maybe the fact that a linear combination of gaussian r.v.s is still a gaussian can help. Indeed $(W(t_1) \ldots W(t_n))$ is a linear combination of $(B(a), B(t_1), \ldots, B(t_n)).$

Comment: @Kore-N how do you kick out $B(t_1+a)$ to $B(t_1)?$ I know that if $X$ is Gaussian then $CX$ is gaussian where $C$ is a matrix $n\times n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $0 \leq t_1 \leq \ldots \leq t_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The vector

$$\begin{pmatrix} B(a) \\ B(t_1+a) \\ \vdots \\ B(t_n+a) \end{pmatrix}$$

is Gaussian, and so is

$$\begin{pmatrix} W(t_1) \\ \vdots \\ W(t_n) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0&0& \ldots & 0& 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0&\ldots & 0 &0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & & & &  & \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots& 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} B(a) \\ B(t_1+a) \\ \vdots \\ B(t_n+a) \end{pmatrix}$$

as a linear combination of Gaussian random vector.

Comment: Thanks, but why the first vector is gaussian? ( I know that $(B(t_1),\ldots,B(t_n))$ is gaussian, so it must be a consequence of this but I don't "see" the argument).

Comment: @Byung $(B(s_1),\ldots,B(s_m))$ is Gaussian for any choice of $s_i$... obviously we can choose $s_1 := a$, $s_2 := t_1+a, \ldots, t_{n+1} := t_n+a$.